# How to retrieve foreign key field in Django rest framework?

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

Given the model and serializer classes below, when I retrieve Track details, it'll only show the Track title but not the related Artist.

How would I also show the Artist name when retrieving Track details?

**models.py**

```
class Artist (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Track (models.Model):    
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name="Artist")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Title")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**serializers.py**

```
class ArtistSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    name = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Artist
        fields = ('id', 'name')

class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you need custom field, try this serializer:

```
class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ('title', 'artist','artist_name')

    artist_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_artists_name')

    def get_artists_name(self, obj):
        return obj.artist.name
```

It produce something like this.

```
[
    {
        "title": "Don't let me down",
        "artist": 2,
        "artist_name": "The Beatles"
    },
    {
        "title": "Summertime",
        "artist": 1,
        "artist_name": "Ella Fitzgerald"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 11):

Try this serializer,

```
class ArtistSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Artist
        fields = '__all__' # or array of fieldnames like ['name_1', 'name_2']

class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    artist = ArtistSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ('title', 'artist')
```

Inorder to retrieve Artist details, which is a ForeignKey model, you need to use a nested serializer in django-rest-framework.

By using the TrackSerializer with a nested ArtistSerializer, the retrieved data would look something like this,

```
{
    "title": "Some_Title",
    "artist": {
                   "id": 2, #or id of the artist.
                   "name": "Artist_name"
               }
}
```

Comment: how do I access artist.name?

Comment: artist name would be in ArtistSerializer, which is included in TrackSerializer

Comment: for example, I don't want to pass all artist fields. just artist.name or a particular field. is there a way to do that?

Comment: Yes, you could just specify the field names in `fields` attribute, maybe like `fields = ['your_field_name', 'other_name_if_available']`

Answer (score 4):

As you can see in the official django rest framework [documentations](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects)
You should define a serializer field for nested items

First create your Artist (nested item) serializer

```
class ArtistSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    name = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Artist
        fields = ('id', 'name')
```

Then you can use it on related model serializers

```
class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    artist = ArtistSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ('title', 'artist')
```

Answer (score 2):

In the current version of DRF you can simply do this

```
class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    artist = serializers.StringRelatedField()

    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = '__all__'
```

`StringRelatedField` may be used to represent the target of the relationship using its `__str__` method.

[REF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#stringrelatedfield)